# How to hide a specific x-axis label programmatically?

Tags: highcharts

Anyone know how to programmatically hide a single xaxis label?

I'm hiding the graphic this way, but I need to do the xaxis label too.

```
.highcharts().series[0].data[1].graphic.hide()
```

Here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/2pyzjdch/

I'd like to hide the banana label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide the label you want in this way:

```
.highcharts().xAxis[0].ticks[1].label.hide();
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/68jyh7so/

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in many ways e. g. updating your xAxis categories on click:

```
chart: {
  type: 'bar',
  events: {
    load() {
      var btnHide = document.getElementById('btnHide'),
        btnShow = document.getElementById('btnShow'),
        chart = this;
      btnHide.addEventListener('click', function() {
        chart.update({
          xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', '', 'Oranges']
          }
        })
      })
      btnShow.addEventListener('click', function() {
        chart.update({
          xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Banaas', 'Oranges']
          }
        })
      })
    }
  }
},
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n87e9gfr/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update